# install4J - customize messages on standard screens

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j 7.0.1 - and I have used 'Installation components' screen. 
This screen has title: 'Select Component' and subtitle: 'Which component should be installed?'. Is there any way how to cutomize these texts?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the General Settings->Languages step, set up a custom localization file, then open the built-in editor and click on the "Override messages" tool bar button. Search for the message you want to change and click on OK. Then you can change the text in the editor.